# What is a good wifi adapter for an E460?

Tags: 16.04, lts

I am running a 16.04 LTS on an E460 thinkpad. I recently realised, from browsing other askubuntu questions (can't find the link to that), that on a high traffic router the signal from my laptop gets drowned out. Given that lenovo uses whitelists (as can be seen [here](https://download.lenovo.com/parts/ThinkPad/e460_intel_frubom_20151030.pdf)), I can just pick a wifi card to replace the current for one that is better supported by a linux operating system.

**HOWEVER**

I do not know which to choose, because I do not know what ubuntu supports well. How do I determine this?

**NOTE**
I would much rather find hardware that works well than to write a script to boost the signal of my wifi card.

Comment: See here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported

Comment: Intel and Atheros chipsets are the least likely to have issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the whitelist problem, I suggest that you consult the Lenovo documentation here: https://download.lenovo.com/parts/ThinkPad/e460_intel_frubom_20151030.pdf

At the very end, you can find the FRUs for wireless devices that were shipped in E460s and are therefore assumed to be accepted in the whitelist. For example, 00JT532. A Google search suggests that this is an Intel 8260NGW. A search of Ask Ubuntu for Intel 8260 and 16.04 suggests that the 8260 is working without any other steps.

Of course, there are several other devices listed and I recommend that you do a similar search of the FRUs before you buy.

Comment: You are right, I found this on the intel site. They state what is supported by [linux](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) better than the [ubuntu libraries](https://download.lenovo.com/parts/ThinkPad/e460_intel_frubom_20151030.pdf)